# How to handle the case when field is not present in Object Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an object something like this in my database and now my requirement is to find the value of particular field such as *name* and if present return true,

```
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "name" : "Team"
}
```

but in some case the field name itself doesn't exist. Sample can be something like this:

```
{
    "id":1234
}
```

In this case I need to return false.

How can I validate if *name* field exist in particular object?

I was trying to use StringUtils method something like this
`StringUtils.isBlank(obj.getName);` 
 But its throwing It is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException .

Comment: What do you mean with "not able to handle it"? What happens when you try it?

Comment: Using `StringUtils.isBlank` should be ok, even in tha case of the name being null. Can you share more of the code and the exception you are getting if you get one. I assume you have no problem creating `obj` and that it reflect the object which is in the database

Comment: It is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException in this case

Comment: What does your class look like? You're showing json above.

Comment: Its an Entity class

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json schema validator. If your json will be in specific format. Please have a look at Jackson library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Gson` Java library to serialize and deserialize Java objects to JSON (as given below).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(object, JsonObject.class);
```

Then, you can use the `has` method in `JsonObject`, to check if the `key` exists in it.

```
jsonObject.has(key)
```

---

Example:

Below is a method to check if given `key` exists in given json string, and get it's value.

(Instead of `String`, you can use your object as well. Here, I am considering the jsonStr as a `String` object, for better understanding.)

```
private String getValueFromJsonForGivenKey(String key, String jsonStr) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class);
    if (jsonObject.has(key)) {
        // The given JSON string has the given key
        String value = jsonObject.get(key).getAsString();
        return value;
    }
    return null;
}
```

For key `id` and for jsonStr `{ "id": "1234" }`, we get `1234`.

For key `name` and for jsonStr `{ "id": "1234" }`, we get `null`.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject class has a method named "has". try this way,

```
if (json.has("name")) {
   String status = json.getString("name"));
}
```

This will work

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use JSONObject's opt method
eg.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
String name = jsonObject.optString("name");
```